# Difference between L += [a] and L.append(a)

Tags: python, list, linked-list, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was wondering: is there any difference between these two methods of appending an element to a list in python:

`L = L + [1]` and `L.append(1)` ?

I mean in a computational way : for example maybe the first method reallocate memory for a new list with size + 1 then copies the content of L into it then append `1`. Or is it rather a linked list where we update the pointer of the next element in the last item of the list. In the latter I think there is no difference (or is there any ?)

Thanks

Comment: Python lists are internally arrays.  `L = L + [1]` has to allocate a new array and copy all the elements; it has `O(n)` complexity.  `L.append(1)` is built such that it only reallocates infrequently; it has `O(1)` amortized complexity.

Comment: In simpler words: in the first way you create a new list, in the second way you modify the original list, therefore the second one is fast